# Left Outer Join using DAX in PowerBI (Many-to-Many Relationship)

Tags: sql, join, business-intelligence, powerbi, dax

How would I do a left join in DAX? When I try to adding a relationship or using the left outer join DAX function I get the following errors (see below). Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

**Error when creating relationship:**
[image: You can't create a relationship between these two columns becasue one of the columns must have unique values.]

**Error when trying NaturalLeftOuterJoin()**
[image: No common join columns detected. The join function 'NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN' requires at-least one common join column.]

For reference, I'm trying to create calculated rows of an income statement. 
Example:

- Revenue: 100
- Cost: 80
- Profit: 20 (Revenue-Cost)

My tables are like below:

```
Fact table:
╔═══════════╦═════════╦═══════════╦════════╗
║ YearMonth ║ StoreID ║ AccountID ║ Amount ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬════════╣
║ 2017-01   ║ A       ║         1 ║    100 ║
║ 2017-01   ║ B       ║         1 ║    200 ║
║ 2017-01   ║ A       ║         2 ║    -50 ║
║ 2017-01   ║ B       ║         2 ║    -50 ║
║ 2017-02   ║ A       ║         1 ║     20 ║
║ 2017-02   ║ B       ║         1 ║    150 ║
║ 2017-02   ║ B       ║         2 ║    -20 ║
╚═══════════╩═════════╩═══════════╩════════╝

Template table:
╔════════════╦═══════════╦═════════╗
║ TemplateID ║ AccountID ║  Line   ║
╠════════════╬═══════════╬═════════╣
║        105 ║         1 ║ Revenue ║
║        105 ║         2 ║ Cost    ║
║        105 ║         1 ║ Profit  ║
║        105 ║         2 ║ Profit  ║
╚════════════╩═══════════╩═════════╝
```

In SQL this is super easy - I just do a left outer join on the AccountID field which creates records for the Profit line, like below:

```
 SELECT 
       f.[YearMonth]
      ,f.[StoreID]
      ,f.[AccountID]
      ,f.[Amount]
      ,t.[TemplateID]
      ,t.[AccountID]
      ,t.[Line]
  FROM [dbo].[Fact] f
  left join [dbo].[Templates] t
  on f.[AccountID] = t.[AccountID]
```

Result:

```
╔═══════════╦═════════╦═══════════╦════════╦════════════╦═══════════╦═════════╗
║ YearMonth ║ StoreID ║ AccountID ║ Amount ║ TemplateID ║ AccountID ║  Line   ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬════════╬════════════╬═══════════╬═════════╣
║ 2017-01   ║ A       ║         1 ║    100 ║        105 ║         1 ║ Revenue ║
║ 2017-01   ║ B       ║         1 ║    200 ║        105 ║         1 ║ Revenue ║
║ 2017-02   ║ A       ║         1 ║     20 ║        105 ║         1 ║ Revenue ║
║ 2017-02   ║ B       ║         1 ║    150 ║        105 ║         1 ║ Revenue ║
║ 2017-01   ║ A       ║         2 ║    -50 ║        105 ║         2 ║ Cost    ║
║ 2017-01   ║ B       ║         2 ║    -50 ║        105 ║         2 ║ Cost    ║
║ 2017-02   ║ B       ║         2 ║    -20 ║        105 ║         2 ║ Cost    ║
║ 2017-01   ║ A       ║         1 ║    100 ║        105 ║         1 ║ Profit  ║
║ 2017-01   ║ B       ║         1 ║    200 ║        105 ║         1 ║ Profit  ║
║ 2017-02   ║ A       ║         1 ║     20 ║        105 ║         1 ║ Profit  ║
║ 2017-02   ║ B       ║         1 ║    150 ║        105 ║         1 ║ Profit  ║
║ 2017-01   ║ A       ║         2 ║    -50 ║        105 ║         2 ║ Profit  ║
║ 2017-01   ║ B       ║         2 ║    -50 ║        105 ║         2 ║ Profit  ║
║ 2017-02   ║ B       ║         2 ║    -20 ║        105 ║         2 ║ Profit  ║
╚═══════════╩═════════╩═══════════╩════════╩════════════╩═══════════╩═════════╝
```

Then I can pivot it like so:

```
╔═════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║  Line   ║ Store A ║ Store B ║
╠═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ Revenue ║     120 ║     350 ║
║ Cost    ║     -50 ║     -70 ║
║ Profit  ║      70 ║     280 ║
╚═════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

In DAX it seems much more complex - hopefully someone can prove me wrong on this! I've read bi-directional filtering may allow many-to-many relationships but I wasnt able to get it working here. The reason I'm trying to do this join in DAX rather than SQL because I have several statement templates and would prefer not having several loads with very similar data if it could be done dynamically through DAX. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried  `NATURALINNERJOIN(<leftJoinTable>, <rightJoinTable>)` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn802543.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Also, take a look at this post https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/from-sql-to-dax-joining-tables/

Comment: Thanks Horaciux, NaturalInnerJoin will not give the desired result (really want a left join), that said, it still produces the same error. I looked at the link, but it didn't make too much sense - was hoping someone may have a solution for this scenario. Thanks for the suggestion though!! : )

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reasons why the `Template` table is needed, other than as dummy for calculations? Because just from the sample data I saw that the fact table is duplicated (7 -> 14 rows) unnecessarily (maybe I'm missing some key points).

If not, you can simply write a few [Measures](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-measures/) in DAX to do the calculations in Power BI (which is exactly the power of Power BI), and only the `Fact` table is needed.

**DAX:**

Revenue:

```
Revenue = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Fact'[Amount]),
    FILTER(
        'Fact',
        'Fact'[Amount] > 0
    )
)
```

Cost:

```
Cost = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Fact'[Amount]),
    FILTER(
        'Fact',
        'Fact'[Amount] < 0
    )
)
```

Profit:

```
Profit = [Revenue] + [Cost]
```

Then you can use a `Matrix` visualization to get the desired results:

[image: result]

P.S. If you really need the Revenue/Cost/Profit to be in the row instead of column, you may need to pivot the data or write the calculations as new `Column` (but not `Measure`) instead. This is due to a [product limitation](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/10948962-matrix-measures-or-values-on-rows-instead-of-colum) in Power BI.

Comment: Thanks Foxan. Yes, need the calculations in a row. Its done using a templates table as there are hundreds of report templates already created.